# Send Email Button

Tags: apex, email, custom-button, apex-email-service

I am trying to create a custom send email button on a custom object called Disease__c. I have patients linked to the disease, where disease is the Master in the master-detail relationship.

Disease__c (Master) ..... Patient__c (Detail) .... Contact (Lookup)

The email button should go on the Disease__c page and when I click the button, I want to send an email (a predefined template) to all patients linked to the disease. I will not need to edit this template.

I have looked at this: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000goIfAAI and it seems to be what I am looking for, however I cannot get it to work, probably because I need to get the correct value for `rtype=` .

I will also need to populate the email with all my patients linked to the disease.

Any ideas on how to go about this? Tia.

Answer (score 1):

@USER8737

try this once by using this template will automatically popuplate, and customer name also automatically populate

```
 location.replace('/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p3_lkid={!sobjecApi__c.Id}&retURL=%2F{!sobjecApi__c.Id}&p2_lkid={!sobjecApi__c.ContactId__c}&template_id=1213244335&new_template=1');
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work as I cannot access the email addresses of my patients in this way.

Answer (score 1):

I found one useful link that explains how EmailAuthor.jsp works.

Please read through and see if you can use p4 ( CC) & p5 (BCC) parameters to send email to many Patients.

http://salesforcewizard.wordpress.com/2014/01/08/great-url-hack-meet-the-chatter-publisher-action/

Answer (score 0):

I have now created a button which calls a webservice class using JavaScript. In my webservice class I will set up the email template and then send the email to all my patients. This works very well.